# Launching activity from the status bar creates new activity even when one already exists

Tags: android

I have an activity that starts a long-running service which in turn adds an icon to the status bar. When the activity gets invisible, e.g. by pressing the Home button, and the pressing the icon in the status bar a new activity is created instead of showing the already created activity. If you now press the back button the new activity is destroyed and the activity created in the first place gets visible. How do I make the invisible activity brought to front when pressing the icon in the status bar instead of creating a new activity?
Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) attribute for the  tag in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Works as intended after I set launchMode to singleInstance. Awesome, thanks!